# HPUX: changing LVM paths or disk device names

Tags: lvm, hp-ux

Our installed HPUX system has a VG called "vg00" whose data was stored in partition "/dev/dsk/c3t5d0s2"

Now that disk failed and we have an exact copy of that disk. However when we use the new disk, the system assigns it the name "/dev/dsk/c3t4d0s2", regardless of the physical slot in the machine where we install the disk.

Is there a way to change the path where the system tries to find the physical disk (that seems to be stored in the /etc/lvmtab file but it's a binary file), or if that's not possible, change the names that the system assigns to devices?

Comment: Why do you want to? Part of the whole point of LVM is avoid the dependency on physical device names like that...

Comment: The system fails to boot otherwise... we can only boot on LVM maintenance mode

Comment: It sounds like you need to export / reimport the VG, rather than changing the physical device's name. The physical name isn't your problem, IMO.

Comment: A question.....did you mirror the root disk?

Comment: exporting the current vg00 and then importing the right partition into vg00 worked!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have the disk configured for SCSI ID 4 instead of SCSI ID 5.  Check the physical disk for this.

I think that what I might do in this case is use vgscan to find all the volume groups and I believe it corrects the problems like this.

However, you might have another problem, the disk boot is not generally contained in a volume group and it is specified by specific device name (on a different partition).  This is usually hardcoded if I recall by both the boot firmware and within some files on the boot partition itself.

Best to contact HP support and have them help you though this.  I have done that before, (in a late night panic when I lost my root volume vg00, after going through a successful Oracle update but not yet having a good backup)....that was a long day!  But HP support did help me through it.

Comment: We did a block copy of the full disk. It has two 500MB FAT  partitions, and the rest is a huge partition with LVM... I think the root HPUX system is inside the LVM, and the FAT partitions are just for EFI